# Asp.Net core website update without server restart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04

i have successfully upload my Asp.net core 1.01 website to Ubuntu 14.04 Vultr VPS with Nginix.

The problem is that whenever i change in my code on local development machine and upload published folder dll to server, its required to restart the application or server to view updated contents.

is someone help me to that without application or server restart. so i can just upload updated dlls via FTP and its show updated contents.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [dotnet-watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch) 
dotnet watch is a tool that runs a dotnet command when source files change. For example, a file change can trigger compilation, tests, or deployment.